# Ubuntu 12.10 dual boot on a small SSD

Tags: dual-boot, 12.10, ssd, system-requirements

I'm thinking about buying a laptop with a setup like this:
- 750 GB HDD
- 32 GB SSD

It comes preinstalled with windows 8. I would like to dual boot Ubuntu 12.10 with it on the SSD and I'm wondering if the 32 GB SSD won't be too small for that. If i remove windows completely then I probably would be fine - but will they both fit ? w8 will probably need something between 16-20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu needs a small amount of space in order to be installed.

The recommendations - requirements are here : [Ubuntu requirements - Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition)

all the rest are depend on you. What and how many programs you want to install.

Of course for data storage you will use the HDD (not the SSD), but is preferable to have the /home directory in the SSD. Many programs relay on the /home directory. Their configuration files are saved in the /home directory as hidden files/folders and so the read speed (opening programs) will be faster.

I think you will be fine and you will be amazed by the speed (of boot and correspondence of Desktop Environment)